# NetBeans IDE is not catching typing errors?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Okay I haven't had a problem with NetBeans in the past. It's my preferred IDE because it will put an error notification type thing next to a line of code that is wrong. Example would be if I forgot a semicolon or accidentally put Jlabel instead of JLabel. Somehow last night it stopped doing that for me. I think maybe I pressed a button or accidentally changed a setting(Or maybe I need to update it?). 
Anyway, if anyone knows how to fix this please let me know as if makes error catching take longer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please update your NetBeans installation.

There were some issues regarding error highlighting recently, but they should be fixed now.